# JS issues appending/ removing child (Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a small puzzle game. When clicking on an image i want an **overlay** to appear which should either show a video (to give players hints) or create a div inside the overlay with an input (to enter a password which should unlock new options/videos if entered correctly).

When showing/hiding the overlay div a "**TypeError: Argument 1 of Node.removeChild is not an object.**" on lines 17, 29 and 86 appears.

System: Windows 10 64bit/ Windows 8 32 Bit running Firefox(67.0.4). It will only ever run on one or two devices using a modern Firefox version.

I tried re-getting the overlay element (through document.getElementById) before trying to add/remove from it. And the objects i'm trying to remove should be getting checked by if statements featuring typeof.

Creating the overlay works, i'm just running into errors trying to close it.

**I've tried** different approaches for over 12h straight and i've decided on reworking it about 4h ago, after a long hot day. Please be kind if i overlooked something^^

Here are the more interesting parts.

```js
//Variables
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

//removes Overlay by adding "hidden" class.
function removeOverlay() {
  if (typeof(document.getElementById("curVid")) !== 'undefined') {
    overlay.removeChild(document.getElementById("curVid"));
  }
  if (typeof(document.getElementById("pwDiv")) !== 'undefined') {
    overlay.removeChild(document.getElementById("pwDiv"));
  }
  overlay.classList.add("hidden");
}

//shows overlay by removing "hidden" class. adds listener for clicks to remove Overlay.
function showOverlay() {
  overlay.classList.remove("hidden");
  overlay.addEventListener('click', function() {
    removeOverlay();
  });
}

//Play Video: receives int for video source. Creates a new Video with all its settings, 
//adds it to the overlay and calls showOverlay function.
function playVideo(id) {
  var vid = document.createElement('video');
  vid.src = getVideo(id);
  vid.id = "curVid";
  vid.autoplay = true;
  vid.controls = true;
  vid.onended = function() {
    overlay.removeChild(vid);
    removeOverlay();
  };
  overlay.appendChild(vid);
  showOverlay();
}


function createPWPromt(password) {
  console.log(password);
  var newsDiv = document.getElementById("news");

  var pwDiv = document.createElement('div');
  pwDiv.id = "pwDiv";
  overlay.appendChild(pwDiv);

  var pwInput = document.createElement('input');
  pwInput.id = "pwInput";
  pwDiv.appendChild(pwInput);

  var pwButton = document.createElement('button');
  pwButton.id = "pwButton";
  pwButton.innerHTML = "senden";
  pwButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (pwInput.value.toLowerCase() == password) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = "hello world the password was correct!";
      newsDiv.appendChild('p');
      removeOverlay();
    } else {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = "sorry the password was incorrect!";
      newsDiv.appendChild('p');
      removeOverlay();
    }
  });
  pwDiv.appendChild(pwButton);

  showOverlay();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Rework</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="video.css">

  <style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="news">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <p onclick="showOverlay()">Show Overlay!</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p onclick="playVideo(4)">Play Video 4!</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p onclick="createPWPromt('nudel')">create PW Promt!</p>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="youtuber">

  </div>
  <div id="overlay" class="hidden">

  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="video.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My Divs are all formatted with float:left; with the 2 for content being at 50% width while the third is positioned absolute at 100% width and height. It has a .hidden class (for display:none) which is added and removed through js to toggle visibility.

Comment: Put the HTML in the question, not a comment.

Comment: The error implies that `document.getElementById()` isn't finding the  ID you're looking for. So it returns `null`, which isn't an object.

Comment: thanks for your quick response. The ID definitly exists when i'm inspecting the website in firefox, and the HTML works as far as i can see. its nothing special really^^. But i will add it below my other code!

Comment: There's nothing in the `overlay` DIV, so how can we click on it? Also, you shouldn't call `overlay.addEventListener()` every time the user clicks on `Show Overlay`, it will run the click listener multiple times.

Comment: There is a function being called (which is not shown in here) which sets the video source. By having my Overlay div at 100% height and width it fills out the window, so there is a lot of space to click at to preemtively close the video(which has been working before).
Ah yeah i've tried moving it out of there though it didn't fix my issue so i left it where it was for now. Where do you recommend me putting it? I guess i could try to include it into my html code.

(I'm not sure about posting the rest of my JS code since the hints on stackoverflow told me to only select the parts with issues.)

Comment: We don't need all the real HTML for the [mcve], just enough so we can try it out. But I already solved the problem, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll get this error if you call `removeOverlay()` before you've added both the `curVid` and `pwDiv` elements. Your test for whether the elements are already there is incorrect. You test whether `document.getElementById()` returns `undefined`, but it returns `null` when the element is not found.

```
function removeOverlay() {
  var curVid = document.getElementById("curVid");
  if (curVid) {
    overlay.removeChild(curVid);
  }
  var pwDiv = document.getElementById("pwDiv");
  if (pwDiv) {
    overlay.removeChild(pwDiv);
  }
  overlay.classList.add("hidden");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the main issue!
I'm still running into the same issue with my `function createPWPromt(password)` in the Event Listener for my button it won't go through adding the p (for testing purposes i commented out the  onclick close function of my overlay div)

Comment: In general, it's considered better style to create all the elements you need in the HTML, and just hide and show them as needed, rather than creating elements on the fly like this.

Comment: oh i see thanks.  Through appending and showing them on use i should be able to move them where i need, right?

Comment: Yes, you can do that, and it's not an uncommon style.